# CSS box-sizing: border-box still adding border size to element width

Tags: html, css

The following example is to demonstrate the problem I'm having.

So if I have a 200px wide container

I add a 200px wide row in the container (will add lots of rows)

I want to add div's to the row that total 200px (different each row)

All works fine until I add in the 1px solid border to the .cont div.

Why is the box-sizing not accounting for the .cont border?

[Edit] the three .cell divs do not show with the border added, without the border all three .cell divs display. [/Edit]

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box !important;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

.cont {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid;
  /* Remove this and it works */
  border-color: purple;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.h_row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: solid;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  border-width: 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cell {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.h_row>.cell {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border-right: solid;
  border-right-color: pink;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.h_row>.cell:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.w50 {
  width: 50px;
}

.w100 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="h_row">
    <div class="cell w100">100</div>
    <div class="cell w50">50</div>
    <div class="cell w50">50</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if i run the snippet from your css & html , i get  a 200px width all togeter including borders . what do i miss ?

Comment: it's exactly accounting for the borders, what you want is to not account for the borders using content-box

Comment: for my test , i used a ruler plugin (for FF 74.0) and `.cont{
  transform:scale(3);
  transform-origin:0 0 ;}` wich  gives me 600px . 600px/3=200px .

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it should show three green boxes 100 50 50 it shows 10 50 and then pushes the next one down a line  - I edit the question to be more clear

Comment: the box drops down because there isn't enough space inside the container, `box-sizing: border-box` does include the border width which means the container will have the overall width of the container minus the width of the border on both sides. which is `200px overall width - border width 1px on each side makes it 2px 200-2 = 198px` which is less than the sum of the widths of the children

Comment: @ZohirSalak that makes perfect sense - that is what I was missing! Thank you.

Comment: fixed your snippet. when i run it in FF, the 3 boxes are on a single line inside a container of 200px  of width. which browser do you use? ff do not show the third box dropping to a ext row. **here is the screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/krKzW.jpg

Comment: @G-Cyrillus there's a third item below, the red box is the background of `h_row` which has `height: 22px;overflow: hidden;` so you can't see the third box

Comment: @ZohirSalak lol i did not even notice  , here is a another reason to be found of flex and give up float and static pixel width.

Comment: Note: the standard now calls for two colons to be used for `before` and `after`.

Comment: the way here would be : 
`.w50 {
  width: 25%;
}

.w100 {
  width: 50%;
}` so it fits inside the 198px left for the children ... nothing wrong with box-sizing

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it was me missing that the .cont div is 200px with 1px border left and right. Therefore the .h_row is 198px with box-sizing as used. I knew it was something simple - just needed a little help finding it!  -Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually very simple.

I was missing that the .cont div is 200px with 1px border left and right.

Therefore the .h_row inside it is 198px with box-sizing as used.

Thus the .cell need to add up to 198px and not 200px.

I knew it was something simple - just needed a little help finding it!

-Thanks @ZohirSalak!

Answer (score 0):

maybe rather than using border you can use a box-shadow but put it inside your box meaning a 1px border basically inside the container

and maybe another way to solve this is to not have pixels sizes you can try using percent for width like 50% or 10%

if you want the code for that you can try this website:
[link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/641671/HTML-element-inner-border)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `box-sizing: content-box;` to exclude border width from element width and container remains 200px.